# How to select the text of a bootstrap tab from inside the element

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a hard time figuring this out, I need to allow selection of the text of the tabs (in this case Page 1), I tried using draggable=false and that works only on firefox but is not working on I.E or chrome.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="id1" href="#tab1" draggable="false">Page 1<span class="closeIcon"></span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="well tab-pane active"><p>Content 1</p></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/997bd1ko/3/

Comment: you have `unselectable="on"` yet you want the text to be selectable? am I missing something here?

Comment: Regardless of `unselectable` the text cannot be highlighted in Chrom when you start the selection from within the element. I could highlight the text ('Page 1') when started the drag (mousedown) outside that element, e.g. 1 cm to the right of the X button, then moving the mouse to the left while still holding down the button.

Comment: sorry about that I removed the property but the result is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried dragging a link in HTML (lets say chrome)? The result is you get an object on your mouse representing the link:

[image: see]

If you override the `-webkit-user-drag: none;` with `-webkit-user-drag: inherit;` on the `<a>` tag of your tab you will notice the exact same behavior.

So what do you do in the usual case? Start dragging from next to the link... hence what you see as a behaviour.

### UPDATE

How about some custom CSS? Take a look at this updated fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/997bd1ko/6/)

```
<li class="active">
     <p class="p-tab" data-toggle="tab" id="id1" href="#tab1" draggable="false">Page 1
         <span class="closeIcon"></span>
     </p>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.p-tab {
    -webkit-user-drag: inherit;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer; /*optional*/
}
```

I have replaced your link `<a>` tag in the tab with a paragraph (`<p>`) and added custom CSS to it that bootstrap applies to the link. Same look, same behavior but selectable =) Hope this helps.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, sadly this doesn't solve the problem. And selecting the correct text from outside the element gets quite tricky when there is more than one tab.